# Resize images, and center horizontally and vertically within container

Tags: html, css, image

I am implementing a carousel with images. The carousel is 960px wide, and contains 5 images in containers of width 960px/5 = 192px (and height 119px).

I want the images to be as large as possible inside their containers, without changing the aspect ratio of the images. I also want the images to be centered both horizontally and vertically within their container.

By hacking around for hours, and using the `center` tag, I have managed to construct what I describe above. Please see a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hfX2h/).

The problem is with the container of the second image (as shown by the black border). While the second image *is* centered horizontally, the container is shifted down a little.

I'm trying to implement an overlay on the images, and need the containers to all be at the same height. How can I have the containers all at the same height? Is there a better/cleaner approach that does not use the `center` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `vertical-align:top;` to your `#carousel-images .image{}` css

Or `middle` or `bottom`...

Uh? Why did I get downvoted on this?

http://jsfiddle.net/y2KV7/

Comment: Could you please provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by doing the following:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="carousel-images">
  <img src="http://eurosensus.org/img/initiatives-300/30kmh.png" />
  <img src="http://eurosensus.org/img/initiatives-300/affordableEnergy.png"/>
  <img src="http://eurosensus.org/img/initiatives-300/basicIncome.jpg"/>
  <img src="http://eurosensus.org/img/initiatives-300/ecocide.jpg"/>
  <img src="http://eurosensus.org/img/initiatives-300/educationTrust.jpg"/>
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper 
{ 
 width: 100%; 
 text-align: center; 
 background: blue; 
}

#carousel-images 
{
 width: 960px;
 white-space: nowrap;
 font-size: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#carousel-images img 
{
 display: inline;
 max-width: 192px;
 max-height: 119px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

***[Click here to view working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2KZtz/)***

Answer (score -2):

First, don't make the world come back to 10 years ago. do not use  tag for formating.  I would also suggest you to get some reading about different between div and span as well as display attribute.  you could easily find information on http://www.w3schools.com.

if you want a center container. you could use css margin auto trick.

like margin:5px auto; would center the container horizontally.

Comment: What? Do you know what "aspect ratio" means?